# C# Generate more exe from one project

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

from your experience is it possible to generate multiple exe from one project? Let me better explain, I have a project where the user, as first action, has to select one "object" (e.g. a book) from a collection and then the GUI starts. I'd like to generate, automatically, also a GUI for each object in case I want to send just a dedicated GUI to dedicated user. Is it possible or I have to insert a project for each "book"?

Thanks a lot

Comment: That sounds like an XY problem. Can't you use commandline parameters to instruct the same executable to do something else?

Comment: Or a config file, or if you are worried about grubby little fingers, use a weblogin like wcf to verify users and control content

Comment: Typically a "project" creates a single exe - but a "solution" can contain multiple projects & create multiple exe's. But your question really is not clear what you actually want - why do you need a separate project for each book?

Comment: This project is not heading the right way.  "Select one object" is a GUI interaction as well.  You can easily create multiple windows in WPF.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be conflating code and content. Typically in a multiple-book sort of scenario, you'd have a single code base, but several modules of content which the code base is capable of running. In your particular case you'd distribute a single .exe and perhaps a series of media files for each title.

In some cases you need custom behavior for certain content. So that may be why you believe you need separate programs. But the requirement to distribute book-specific behavior could still be achieved with a single main executable and a [pluggable framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972962.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), e.g. you may wish to distribute one assembly per book, and that assembly could expose a class with a specific interface. But the whole thing would still run within a single .exe.

Answer (score 0):

Always think about the architecture.

If you want to create two application which shares a lot of common code, then there are multiple ways to achive this.

1. Use command line switch to application, on the start of the application on which decide on which mode the application will work on. One exe will swich to different modes accordingly.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/command-line-arguments
2. Share the common code in one module (.Net Projec) and create a solution with multiple bootstrap project.

In your visual studio solution you can create multiple projects. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h970wzkb.aspx